# TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '-'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to make a form with flask, and I made a macro to paint the form but I get this error, I have no idea what could happen. in the video that I'm watching, they do not close the import of the macro

_macro.html

```html
{% macro render-biseccion(field) %}
  <td> {{field.label}}
  <dd> {{field(**kwargs) | safe }}
{% endmacro %}
```

biseccion.html

```html
{%extends 'base/base.html'%}

{% block content %}
  {% from "_macro.htm" import render-biseccion %}
    <form>
      {{render-biseccion(form.xi)}}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is it normal you import `_macro.htm` instead of `_macro.html`?

Comment: I think you can't have a hyphen `-` in your variable names. Replace that with an underscore `_` everywhere. (`render_biseccion` instead of `render-biseccion`)

Comment: Thank you very much!!
if I had to remove the (-) macro function

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen in a `render-biseccion` will violate the naming rules. Replace it with an underscore (`_`)